# Angular.js orderBy:sortColumn is not sorting the selected column

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

Here @Model.jsonString is a string

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Car
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<html>

<head>

    <title></title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link href="~/Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myModule">
<div ng-controller="myContoller" ng-init="init(@Model.jsonString)">

    OrderBy : <select ng-model="sortColumn">
        <option value="+Mileage">Mileage Asc</option>
        <option value="+Name">Name Asc</option>
        <option value="+Model">Model Asc</option>
        <option value="+Engine">Engine Asc</option>
        <option value="+Color">Color Asc</option>

    </select>
    <table class="table">
        <thead >

            <tr class="th">
                <th>Mileage</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Engine</th>
                <th>Color</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr ng-repeat="car in cars | orderBy:sortColumn">
                <td>{{car.mileage}}</td>
                <td>{{car.name}}</td>
                <td>{{car.model}}</td>
                <td>{{car.engine}}</td>
                <td>{{car.color}}</td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


</body>




</html>
```

Here is the code for script.js

```
/// <reference path="angular.js" />
var app = angular
    .module("myModule", [])
    .controller("myContoller",
        function ($scope) {

            $scope.init = function(jsonString) {
                //This function is sort of private constructor for controller

                $scope.cars = jsonString;


            };
            $scope.sortColumn = "Name";
        });
```

I'm trying to sort all the columns and the orderBy:sortColumn seems to be not working for some reason. Any hint would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think I've used the right keyword. Can you please point out where it went wrong. Thanks @adam0101

Comment: did you tried to define the ngRepeat like this: `<tr ng-repeat="car in cars | orderBy:'name'">` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select box value names should be same name as array property name. And remove the plus icon also. use `-` in front of it only if you need to order item in descending order

```js
angular
 .module("myModule", [])
 .controller("myContoller", function($scope) {
  $scope.init = function(jsonString) {
   //This function is sort of private constructor for controller
   $scope.cars = [  
         {  
            'mileage':'16',
            'name':'asss',
            'model':'sst',
            ' engine':'aagaa',
            'color':'yellow'
         },
         {  
            'mileage':'14',
            'name':'sss',
            'model':'sdt',
            ' engine':'avaaa',
            'color':'red'
         },
         {  
            'mileage':'12',
            'name':'dsss',
            'model':'sgt',
            ' engine':'aaaaa',
            'color':'blue'
         }
      ];
  };
     $scope.init ()
  $scope.sortColumn = "Name";
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myModule">
<div ng-controller="myContoller" 
 >

    OrderBy : <select ng-model="sortColumn">
        <option value="mileage">Mileage Asc</option>
        <option value="name">Name Asc</option>
        <option value="model">Model Asc</option>
        <option value="engine">Engine Asc</option>
        <option value="color">Color Asc</option>

    </select>
    <table class="table">
        <thead >

            <tr class="th">
                <th>Mileage</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Engine</th>
                <th>Color</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr ng-repeat="car in cars | orderBy:sortColumn">
                <td>{{car.mileage}}</td>
                <td>{{car.name}}</td>
                <td>{{car.model}}</td>
                <td>{{car.engine}}</td>
                <td>{{car.color}}</td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day. My upvote doesn't count because I have only 1 reputation. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your option values have uppercase letters, but your object properties have lowercase letters.